# How can I initialize an indeterminate number of Spinners?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am making an app that allows users to create fitness goals. This app asks users to input a number of activities that they are interested in (e.g. running, lifting, biking). Next, it goes to a screen where it asks for goals for each of these activities (e.g. "Lose weight," "Bulk up," "Have fun"). I want this second screen to be a ScrollView composed of an indeterminate number of Spinners, with each of these Spinners containing a set of pre-written goals. Currently, I am assuming that there are only five interests selected. I am doing this:

```
goalSpinners = new Spinner[numInterests];
goalSpinners[0] = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.firstSpinner);
goalSpinners[1] = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.secondSpinner);
goalSpinners[2] = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.thirdSpinner);
goalSpinners[3] = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.fourthSpinner);
goalSpinners[4] = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.fifthSpinner);
```

This, of course, is a problem when there are more than five interests selected. How can I have it where I can load the *n*th Spinner in a ScrollView?

Comment: Why not use `ListView/RecyvlerView`?

Comment: What are the differences between a RecyclerView and a ScrollView?

Comment: In general `RecyclerView` - container for items, `ScrollView` - container just for scroll. For beggining try simple `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Collect the number of activities in the first screen, send this number to the second screen where you create an array of Spinners based on this number. In this way, the number of spinners will be dynamically defined based on user input.

For sending data from one Activity to another, you can use a Bundle (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)

Use a listview/recyclerView consisting of individual elements, each element consisting of a spinner and additional controls as needed.

You can refer to this tutorial to create a custom listview http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67.

Modify it accordingly to contain your spinners. That way the number of spinner you need will be created dynamically based on the number of activities, and you can access each based on the *position* of that list element.

Comment: Sorry if I did not make it clear enough, but this is what I am already doing. numInterests is the number of selected activities that is passed in a bundle.

Comment: Use a listview consisting of list elements, each consisting of a spinner. Updating my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer.